# How do I uninstall Ubuntu One on Windows 7?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, uninstall

Just tried Ubuntu One ver.2 on Windows 7 and got into trouble with syncing. The installer did not make any entry in the Control Panel Install/Remove programs.

How do I uninstall/remove the files/settings etc. completely?

Answer (score 6):

Or choose "Uninstall Ubuntu One" from the start menu.

And then remove this folder:

```
c:\program files\ubuntuone
```

and if you're on 64-bit:

```
c:\program files (x86)\ubuntuone
```

Then in the Control Panel → Credentials, remove the "Ubuntu One" key.

Comment: _Thank you all_, it started with a broken installation (some files deleted) - the Ubuntu One was reinstalled and then successfully uninstalled!

Answer (score 2):

`C:\Program Files\ubuntuone\uninstall.exe --mode win32` is your friend.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall it manually on Windows 7:

1) Delete credentials: go to the control panel, search for "credentials", then remove the one that says "Ubuntu One"

2) Kill ubuntu one processes: Using the task manager kill the ubuntuone-syncdaemon, ubuntuone-control-panel-qt and windows-ubuntu-sso-client processes

3) Remove the c:\program files\ubuntuone (or c:\program files(x86)\ubuntuone) folder

This will only leave a couple of harmless registry keys and the start menu entries that you can delete manually.

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest of you go to `C:\Program Files\ubuntuone\` and double-click the file called `uninstall.exe`.