# Uninstall ubuntu one for windows 7

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7, uninstall

I recently installed ubuntu one for windows and now would like to uninstall it.  Problem is; there is no uninstall.exe to be found in the start menu or in the ubuntuone folder. There is a Uninstall Ubuntu One shortcut, but it does not lead anywhere.  Also I cannot delete the folder because it says it is in use.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Does Ubuntu One show up in your program list in the Control Panel (under "Add or Remove Programs", I think)?

Comment: Also: have you tried looking at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64212/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-one-on-windows-7) to see if it solves your problem?

Comment: No, it does not show up in the Control Panal

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall it manually on Windows 7:

1) Delete credentials: go to the control panel, search for "credentials", then remove the one that says "Ubuntu One"

2) Kill ubuntu one processes: Using the task manager kill the ubuntuone-syncdaemon, ubuntuone-control-panel-qt and windows-ubuntu-sso-client processes

3) Remove the c:\program files\ubuntuone (or c:\program files(x86)\ubuntuone) folder

This will only leave a couple of harmless registry keys and the start menu entries that you can delete manually.

Comment: This has been copied without attribution from an answer from the duplicate link. Do not do this, if the questions are so similar that an answer works in both, then they are duplicates and should be closed as such.